# Error: Stray '#" in program (SWIG)

Tags: c, swig

I am using RHEL 6 and trying to compile some code using SWIG.

The SWIG file is named mySwig.i and looks like

```
   %module base_module
   %{
     #include "base.h"
   %}
   %include "base.h"
```

The mySwig.i file is kept in a folder named foo.  The folder foo also has other .h, .c and .cxx files.

The command I use is

```
    gcc -fpic -c foo/*
```

The output is:

```
    foo/mySwig.i:1 error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
    foo/mySwig.i:3 error: stray '#' in program
    foo/mySwig.i:5 error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve these errors?

Comment: You can't compile the SWIG specification file as a C++ source file! You need to convert it first to a source file with a special program. On another note, you tagged this question C++, but you use `gcc` to compile instead of e.g. `g++`.

Comment: Hi Joachim, thanks for your reply.  I believe the .i file is compiled by SWIG to a .cxx file.  If I remove the .i file from the directory I get other errors about "linker input file unused because linking not done". How would I go about converting it?  If SWIG generates a .cxx file and the rest of the code is .c files, which compiler should I use, gcc or g++ (Sorry, I'm new with compiling on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -fpic -c foo/*` will match *all* files in the directory foo/. You only want to match C files most likely. You can do what with `gcc -fpic -c foo/*.c` if you really want.

Personally I'd recommend using something like CMake or Autotools, or even just a Makefile to build your project rather than calling cc directly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  When I try that I get other errors about "linker input file unused because linking not done". I'm unfamiliar with using CMake/Autotools so I was looking for a quick and dirty way to correctly compile the code.

Comment: @user973479 My advice: forget SWIG and start with a book or tutorial on C on Linux. For example http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/eecs/spring2011/cs261/resources/gcc_tutorial.pdf seems like good advice.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. SWIG is essential for generating JNI for the project.  This compiled fine using SWIGWin on Windows, so I assumed it may be a simple fix to get rid of that 1 error message since everything else compiles fine.

Comment: @user973479 your problem is not SWIG related at all. You need to understand how to compile and link things. Probably you want to do `gcc -fPIC foo/*.c -shared -o libfoo.so -lwhateveryoulinkagainst`, but understanding the bigger picture and build systems would be well worth it.